# How would a quantum computer potentially facilitate artificial consciousness, assuming it is possible?

Tags: philosophy, research, artificial-consciousness, quantum-computing

How would a quantum computer potentially facilitate artificial consciousness, assuming it is possible?

Comment: Well, this is quite deep question. I would recommend you to have a look on the UK physicist Roger Penrose: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Penrose
He has some books on the theme of consciousness and quantum mechanics. There are however critics of his ideas. One of them is that the quantum effects are too small to direct any considerable influence on the brain.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding which books?

Comment: @nbro I just picked them up myself, and haven't had a chance to read, but I believe the two chief books are "The Emperor's New Mind" and "Shadows of the Mind".